# How do I make multiple directories at once in a directory?

Tags: linux, command-line

I know with mkdir I can do `mkdir A B C D E F` to create each directory.  How do I create directories A-Z or 1-100 with out typing in each letter or number?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's probably easiest to just use a `for` loop:

```
for char in {A..Z}; do
    mkdir $char
done

for num in {1..100}; do
    mkdir $num
done
```

You need at least bash 3.0 though; otherwise you have to use something like `seq`

Comment: Michael thanks!  being curious I also tried it adding test in front of $char 

      for char in {A..Z}; do
    mkdir test$char
done

   which gave me directories test[A-Z], always good to learn

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is how your file names will be sorted when you list them or use them with wildcards like *.  '11' will sort before '2'.  This can be avoided if you arrange for all the numbers to be the same length with leading zeros.  Dennis Williams shows how to do that in bash 4, but you can code your script to do it if you don't have bash 4.

Answer (score 76):

The `{}` syntax is Bash syntax not tied to the `for` construct.

```
mkdir {A..Z}
```

is sufficient all by itself.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion

Comment: Oh, that's spectacular. This is a much better answer

Comment: I didn't know this, great tip!

Comment: +1 for beauty, +1 for style, +1 for [rcrowley](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/506/rcrowley)

Comment: +500 bounty from me.

Comment: This is awesome! just used it: `mkdir -p ./logs-{1..5}`

Comment: This works up to a point when the number of arguments given to `mkdir` becomes too many. At that point, a loop would be needed.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do more complex combinations (try these with `echo` instead of `mkdir` so there's no cleanup afterwards):

Compare

```
$ echo pre-{{F..G},{3..4},{m..n}}-post
pre-F-post pre-G-post pre-3-post pre-4-post pre-m-post pre-n-post
```

to

```
$ echo pre-{F..G}{3..4}{m..n}-post
pre-F3m-post pre-F3n-post pre-F4m-post pre-F4n-post pre-G3m-post pre-G3n-post
pre-G4m-post pre-G4n-post
```

If you have Bash 4, try

```
$ echo file{0001..10}
file0001 file0002 file0003 file0004 file0005 file0006 file0007 file0008 file0009
file0010
```

and

```
$ echo file{0001..10..2}
file0001 file0003 file0005 file0007 file0009
```

Answer (score 7):

On Linux you can generate sequences of digits with the "seq" command, but this doesn't exist on all Unix systems.  For example to generate directories from 1 to 100:

```
mkdir `seq 1 100`
```

While you can certainly make directories A to Z with shell utils:

```
seq 65 90 \
    | while read foo; do printf "%b\n" `printf '\\\\x%x\n' $foo`; done \
    | xargs mkdir
```

It's probably a lot less ugly to just use Perl:

```
perl -e 'foreach (ord "A"..ord "Z") { mkdir chr $_ }'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### YAA ( Yet Another Answer ;)

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), there is a lot of thing you can do! Simple sample:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mkdirdemo/1stLev_{R..T}{0..2}/2ndL_{one,two,three}_{a..c}{a..z}/3rd_{30..42}
```

This will create 9 directories, with 2106 subdirectories and 27378 third level subdirs.

```
ls -d /tmp/mkdirdemo/1stLev_*/*/*|wc -l
27378
find /tmp/mkdirdemo -mindepth 3 -type d | wc -l
27378

$ find /tmp/mkdirdemo -mindepth 3 -type d|sort|sed -ne '1,2p;27377,$p;3s/.*/.../p'
/tmp/mkdirdemo/1stLev_R0/2ndL_one_aa/3rd_30
/tmp/mkdirdemo/1stLev_R0/2ndL_one_aa/3rd_31
...
/tmp/mkdirdemo/1stLev_T2/2ndL_two_cz/3rd_41
/tmp/mkdirdemo/1stLev_T2/2ndL_two_cz/3rd_42
```

Answer (score -1):

`mkdir direct{1..3}` will result in `mkdir direct1 direct2 direct3` and so on . Same for `{a..z}`

Comment: this is a reiteration of three existing answers *and* the one that I already commented on

Answer (score -2):

mkdir {A..Z}
mkdir {0..100}
mkdir test_{A..Z}
and so on.

Comment: I do not get it

Comment: this [has already been covered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640/117549)