# brace expansion other commands besides mkdir?

Tags: brace-expansion

Found this nifty lifehacking gem to create multiple directories: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640/7768

I was wondering if there are other commands support brace expansion?

Comment: As explained in the answers there, brace expansion is a feature of the shell. What else do you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The braces are a shell expansion, so you can use them with any command.  For the record, it doesn't have to be `..`, and it doesn't have to be letters.  Numbers work with a range, you can use commas for independent values, and you can mix it with regular tokens or other expansions:

```
$ echo {1..3} {a..c} {1..3}-{a,c}
1 2 3 a b c 1-a 1-c 2-a 2-c 3-a 3-c
```

And you can nest, which I often use for installing/uninstalling (`{,un}installing` :) ) packages.

```
aptitude install package{,-{dev,doc}}
```

which expands to

```
package package-dev package-doc
```

Answer (score 4):

Further more, it can even have regular expressions. A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or **a valid sequence expression**. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.
Example:

```
mkdir /usr/local/src/bash/{old,new,dist,bugs}
chown root /usr/{ucb/{ex,edit},lib/{ex?.?*,how_ex}}
```

http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion

Comment: Can it be used to copy a single file to multiple targets?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Lee No, not with `cp`, because `cp` only supports a single target. Braces are a way to pass several names to one command without having to write each name in full separately. They know nothing about files and such.