# shell symbol for the just previously typed item?

Tags: bash

Is there a way I can specify to bash to reuse the item I just previously typed? For instance, if I wanted to rename a file, adding a few characters as a prefix, I want to do something like

```
$> mv file.txt new_{prev}
```

and end up with `new_file.txt`.

Is there such a symbol?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use braces(`{}`), but in a somewhat different way. Within braces, `prefix{x,y,z...}suffix`, will expand to put each comma-separated piece between `prefix` and `suffix`:

```
$ mv {,new_}file.txt
```

This will expand to `mv file.txt new_file.txt`. You can also do this with number or letter ranges, `{a..d}` will expand to `a b c d`, `{1..4}` will expand to `1 2 3 4`. You can use only one or the other within a level of braces, but you can nest:

```
$ echo {a,c,{1..3}}
a c 1 2 3
```

For more about brace expansion, see this question: [brace expansion other commands besides mkdir?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25936/11750)

Answer (score 8):

You can define an editing function that copies the previous word under the cursor.

```
copy_preceding_word () {
  local prefix suffix word
  prefix="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}"
  suffix="${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
  if [[ $prefix =~ ([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
    word=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    READLINE_LINE="$prefix$word$suffix"
    ((READLINE_POINT += ${#word}))
  fi
}
bind -x '"\e\C-_": copy_preceding_word'
```

Comment: Excellent readline solution! This does **exactly** what user394 asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\ej": "!#:$\e^"
```

`!#` is the current line, `$` is the last word, and `\e^` is `history-expand-line`.

Comment: nice, thanks. Just for beginners like me: `\ej` is alt-j, and what this does it duplicates the last word in edit buffer.