# Is there a way to define a bash readline command?

Tags: bash, readline

I can not find a way to do that from [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands). So Is there a way to define a bash readline shortcut that will insert a dynamically generated string at the position of the cursor?

E.g., I want to insert date:

```
bind '"\C-xx": my-dynamical-date'

aaa  bbb
--------
    ^ cursor is here

# After pressing "\C-xx":

aaa Sun Apr 22 22:19:00 CST 2018 bbb
------------------------------------
                                ^ cursor is here
```

So how to define my-dynamical-date readline command?

Comment: Do what, exactly? Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can redefine a keybinding, for example `bind '"^M":"\nmy-alias\n"'`

Comment: @terdon I forgot my example and it is given now.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I have given my example :)

Comment: I edited to explain what I think you want to do. Please correct it if I'm wrong.

Comment: @terdon You are right :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can bash write to its own input stream?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213799/can-bash-write-to-its-own-input-stream)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put text in the bash command line buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82630/put-text-in-the-bash-command-line-buffer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit silly but it could be something like this:

```
bind '"\C-xx":"$(date) \e\C-e\ef\ef\ef\ef\ef"'
```

It first enters a literal `$(date)`, then calls `shell-expand-line`
and then moves 5 words forward.

To save the keybinding, add the following to `inputrc`:

```
"\C-xx":"$(date) \e\C-e\ef\ef\ef\ef\ef"
```

Comment: Nice! Any idea how to do this in `.inputrc`? I tried but couldn't figure out how to have a command substitution (`$(command)`) be expanded from the `.inputrc` file.

Comment: @terdon: I've just the added the line above to my `~/.inputrc` and run `bind -f .inputrc`.  I pressed `C-x x` a couple of times and a current time was displayed each time.

Comment: `shell-expand-line` can be used like this! It's great!

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk ah! I hadn't noticed the `\e\C-e` for `shell-expand-line`! That's what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: The only solution to get that in .inputrc. Could you make `shell-expand-line` work in ipython, python or perl REPL ?

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function that edits the readline variables `READLINE_POINT` and `READLINE_LINE`.  For example, set in your `.bashrc`:

```
_myinsert() { # add date at point
    local TOADD=$(date)
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}${TOADD}${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    READLINE_POINT=$(($READLINE_POINT + ${#TOADD}))
}
# cannot put this in ~/.inputrc
bind -x '"\C-xx":_myinsert'
```

This uses the `-x` option of bind to call your function. I don't know of any way to put the equivalent in a `~/.inputrc` file. (You certainly cannot just begin the line with `-x`, for example).