# Use environment variable in .inputrc keybinding

Tags: arch-linux, environment-variables, inputrc

I'd like to add a keybinding to my `.inputrc` that puts the value of an environment variable, `USER`, on the command line.

I tried all kinds of escaping but the string `$USER` is written verbatim to the command line, not the value of that environment variable.

```
$if mode=vi
  # Keymaps when we are in insert mode
  set keymap vi-insert

  # Insert path before mountpoint
  "C-e": "/run/media/$USER"
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this with `.inputrc` or am I better off using other means like `.bashrc`?

Comment: Note, if you have a partly typed command with $variables in it, you can have them expanded by calling the readline function `shell-expand-line`, which you can bind to some character sequence.

Comment: Check out a similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439280/119298).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User meuh's tip to use `shell-expand-line` led me to this solution which puts the environment variable's value on the command line:

```
$if mode=vi
  # Keymaps when we are in insert mode
  set keymap vi-insert

  # Expand variables like ~ and $USER to their values
  "\C-a": shell-expand-line
  # Insert path before mountpoint, then expand the variable
  "\C-e": "/run/media/$USER/\C-a"
```

Now, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> results in `/run/media/me/` on the command line.

Comment: Oh, nicely. If I was using `bash`, I might make some kind of use of this.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting the literal string `$USER` rather than the expanded value of the `USER` variable may not make a big difference, as the variable is likely defined with the proper value (assuming a Linux system) and would be expanded by the shell.

---

This answers an earlier incarnation of the question:

You can not use environment variables in `.inputrc`.

To incorporate the username of the current user in `bash`'s primary prompt, set `PS1` to a value containing the escape sequence `\u`.

See the section labelled "PROMPTING" in the `bash` manual.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kusalananda! I was thinking of putting text on the command line, not changing the command prompt. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Ah, in that case, since `$USER` is most likely a valid environment variable on Linux systems (other systems use `$LOGUSER`), then I don't really see a problem with having the literal string `$USER` inserted. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You're right, thinking about it, it's not a big difference between `/run/media/$USER/` and `/run/media/me/` for my purposes. Path completion works as well using bash on Arch Linux.