# Creating multiple directories using a parameter in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, parameter, mkdir

I'm trying to make a bash script that would make a series of directories 
and requesting a parameter of how many directories should be created.

```
$> ./createDir.sh 5

$> ls

ex_01
ex_02
ex_03
ex_04
ex_05
```

I tried using mkdir ex_{01..$1} but it does not seem correct.
How could I make this work (without using any loop)?

Comment: it is ! We haven't seen the loops yet and it should be easier than making loops.
Is it me having the syntax wrong or is it not possible to use a parameter in this case?

Comment: That's zsh syntax, replace `#! /bin/bash` with `#! /bin/zsh`

Comment: Similar: [difference between `for i in {1..$N}` and `for i in $(seq 1 1 $N) `](/a/103122)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `eval` for this.

```
#!/bin/bash

start=1
stop=$1

mkdir $(eval echo ex_{$start..$stop})
```

But I agree with don_crissti, why not simply use a loop?

Before:

```
ls -p | grep 'ex_'
<empty>
```

After I run the script:

```
./makeDirs.sh 3
ls -p | grep 'ex_'
ex_1/
ex_2/
ex_3/
```

---

Further reading:

- **[Why is eval bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead#17529221)**
- [Variables in bash seq replacement ({1..10})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191146/variables-in-bash-seq-replacement-1-10#6191382)
- [How do I make multiple directories at once in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636/how-do-i-make-multiple-directories-at-once-in-a-directory)

Comment: Good on including the "why is eval bad" link.

Comment: No need for `echo`. `eval "mkdir ex_{$start..$stop}"` should be enough.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, you're right. Works without `echo` as well.